# class based on timerotatingfilehandler does not write anything in logs

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7, time, rotation

I wrote this from help from the logging cookbook [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook)
this code was supposed to write a line for each "device". It creates the log files, but nothing is written inside.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import unicode_literals

import json
import logging
import glob
import logging.handlers

# This next bit is to ensure the script runs unchanged on 2.x and 3.x
try:
    unicode
except NameError:
    unicode = str

class LogWriter:
    Name = 'LogWriter'
    def __init__(self, Device_ID, Severity, Message):
        self.id = Device_ID
        self.severity = Severity
        self.message = Message
        self.logfile = './log/log_'+self.id+'.log'

    def log(self):
        # Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
        logwriter = logging.getLogger('LogWriter')
        logwriter.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # Add the log message handlers to the logger
        timedRotatingLogFileHandler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(self.logfile, when = 'midnight', backupCount=2)
        #setup formatting
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(processName)-10s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
        timedRotatingLogFileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logwriter.addHandler(timedRotatingLogFileHandler)

        try:
            logging.info(self.message, self.severity)
        except:
            return 1
        return 0

def main():
    for i in range(20):
        logger = LogWriter(str(i), 'INFO', 'hello'+str(i))
        logger.log()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working please?

Comment: just saw that the link i gave was 3.x documentation, and that this question got tagged to python-3.x - I'm actually running 2.7 - does it make a difference.

Comment: added correct link to 2.7 logging cookbook so no confusion is created

Comment: I don't see any log - logwriter.log(logging.INFO, self.message) or something like, only info

Comment: `logwriter.log(logging.INFO, self.message)` does not work.  but something like `logwriter.log(logging.INFO+' '+self.message)` works. Would you know of a way to make logwriter.log write more than one string?

Comment: your code work for me, with logwriter.log(loglevel, message). More than 1 message is not usual for log and at module level, msg = ("%s" % msg) so only one string can go thru

Comment: ok. the easy way to get this done was to use getattr() to supply the severity. I've taken the log handlers out of the class definition, and now using child loggers instead of reopening the same logger, since that made duplicate entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both cox and Vinay were correct, but no explicit solution was provided. cox's solution didn't fully work because his suggested definition would hard code the severity not allowing modification by the calls

so I'm no longer passing the device_ID, severity and message to the class, but directly to the log() function

This was the easiest way i got this done.

```
a = getattr(logwriter, severity) 
a(message)
```

replacing

```
logging.info(self.message, self.severity)
```

Best practices are to not create handlers inside the class definition as Vinay said. The solution i found  for that is to define a separate logger module, attach the handlers outside the class definition in the module, create the new logger only once in the calling program, and then each new logger request can log to a child log as explained in the logging cookbook.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a handler to the 'LogWriter' logger, but logging to the root logger, which has no handlers added to it.

It's not good practice to add handlers and set levels except just once from a `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause, it's not really clear from your posted code whether you're following the right practice.

Comment: `logging.info(self.message, self.severity)` 

has now been changed to 

`a = getattr(logwriter, severity)
    a(message)`


and it works